Aggregating both null and not null counts in a single query
What is an elegant way to get a summary of records with both Null and non-Null values in a particular field/column, in a single query?
I'm using this, sort of works but the non-Null has to be calculated from the results. Table in question is called 'BatchHeaders', the concerned field is 'Updated', a 'Date' field, considered 'Not Updated' when Null.
WITH TableA as (
  SELECT 
    count(Id) as Total,
    1 as Idx 
  FROM BatchHeaders
)
SELECT 
  TableA.Total, 
  count(Id) as NotUpdated,
  1 as Idx 
FROM BatchHeaders 
JOIN TableA on TableA.IDX=Idx 
WHERE Updated is NULL;


Would the join from the BatchHeaders table to TableA always be one-to-one?  Can you add some sample data?

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

COUNT(updated) already counts the number if NOT NULL values...
SELECT 
   COUNT(*)                    AS total,
   COUNT(updated)              AS updated,
   COUNT(*) - COUNT(updated)   AS not_updated 
FROM
   BatchHeaders


you can do this without the WITH clause as below.
SELECT 
COUNT(Id) AS Total,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Updated IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NotUpdated,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Updated IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Updated
FROM BatchHeaders;


Even the CASE expression is not needed... COUNT(updated) already disregards the NULLs
